# Generic EventArgs and extension method

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I was looking over the internet for a way to fire events easier and I found this extension class:

```
public static class EventExtensions
{
    public static void Fire<TEventArgs>(this EventHandler<TEventArgs> @event, object sender, TEventArgs e)
        where TEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        if (@event != null)
            @event(sender, e);
    }
}
```

This allows me to fire event using

```
TestEvent.Fire(this,new CallEventArgs(1,"OK"));
```

instead of

```
if(TestEvent != null)
    TestEvent(this, new CallEventArgs(1,"OK"));
```

Because I need to pass some arguments to my events I thought I will create generic EventArgs class:

```
public class EventArgs<T> : EventArgs
{
    public EventArgs()
    {
        Value = default(T);
    }

    public EventArgs(T aValue)
    {
        Value = aValue;
    }

    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

With this I can declare my event as:

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs<MyClass>> TestEvent;
```

and fire it with:

```
if(TestEvent != null)
    TestEvent(this, new EventArgs<MyClass>(new MyClass{Id = 1, Description = "OK"}));
```

My questions are:

1.How should I modify my extension method to be able to call my event as below?

```
TestEvent.Fire(...);
```

2.Is it good practise to extend events and then write extension methods to them this way?

Comment: I'm ashamed - I had different namespaces in my code than in question. Everything works fine. Sorry for trouble

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You don't need to modify anything, your extension method should work fine with generic `EventArgs<T>`.
2. This approach is fine, there's nothing wrong about it.
3. You may want to add the following overload:

   ```
   public static void Fire<T> (this EventHandler<EventArgs<T>> @event, object sender, T value)
   {
       if (@event != null)
           @event(sender, new EventArgs<T>(value));
   }
   ```

   This way, you'll be able to fire events like this:

   ```
   TestEvent.Fire(sender, new MyClass{Id = 1, Description = "OK"});
   ```

Comment: I had error in my code, when I wrote question I correct code in question. After simple fix in my code everything is working. Anyway thanks for answering part 2 of my question :)

Comment: Thanks again! Nice overload, I didn't think about that, any other usefull things I could add there? :)

Comment: If you need to fire only your own events, there's not much to add. Unfortunately, C# treats identical delegates of different types as different, so these extension methods won't work on many of events declared in the framework itself. There's not much to do about it, as far as I know, besides adding more and more overloads.

Comment: I need this only for my events, for now I only use this type of events. Thanks!